# Limit of ${a_n}^{1/n}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

Today my lecturer put up on the board that:

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists and $a_n>0$ then

$\displaystyle \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

however I am not sure why this is true, can somebody give me a hint or something as to how to go about proving this.

thanks for any help

Comment: $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}= e^{\frac{ \ln (a_n)}{n}} \,. $ Do you know how to calculate the limit in the exponent? ;)

Comment: Why the limsup?

Comment: Also, this would be a nice thing to ask the lecturer.

Comment: @Didier: I *think* it was the limsup; the OP had `\lim` followed by `\mathrm{sup}`; I guess it could have been the limit of the suprema instead...

Comment: You left out the assumption $a_n > 0$.  
Hint: if $a_{n+1}/a_n \ge K$ for all $n \ge N$ then $a_n/a_N \ge \ldots$.  Similarly for $\le$.

Comment: It has to be limsup. There is a simple alternating example to show that lim does not always exists. (Only the other way round.)

Comment: Yeah it was meant to be limsup, @ArturoMagidin sorry about that I must have made a typo thanks for the edit

Comment: @abatkai, *There is a simple alternating example* showing that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ converges but $(a_n)^{1/n}$ diverges? Is there? Most curious to see your example, I must say.

Comment: ok  sorry but imnot really getting anywhere with this sorry, could I get some more help or if it should be obvious from what you have said (and I just can't get it) could I have a solution to look at, thanks for all the help

Comment: @user, right, the hypothesis that $a_n$ is positive is missing.

Comment: Realised that, that's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: Further hint: if $a_n/a_N \le \ldots$, then $a_n^{1/n} \le \ldots$.  Note that for any $c > 0$, $c^{1/n} \to c^0 = 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In fact, the stronger statement is as follows:

> **Theorem:** Let $\{c_n\}$ be any sequence in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Then, $\displaystyle \underline{\lim}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\leq \underline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}$ and $\displaystyle \overline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}\leq \overline{\lim}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$.

So, with this, if we assume that $\displaystyle \lim\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ exists then we have that $\displaystyle \overline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}\leq\overline{\lim}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\underline{\lim}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\leq \underline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}$ from where it easily follows that $\overline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}=\underline{\lim}\sqrt[n]{c_n}$ and so $\lim \sqrt[n]{c_n}$ exists and, in fact, it's also clear it must be equal to $\displaystyle \lim\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$. A proof of this fact can be found on page 68 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. I assume you have access to this (very well-known) book--if not say so and I shall give an outline of the proof.

Comment: I don't at the moment and will not for about a week, would it be possible for you to outline the proof. (I will have my book back in a while so if you are busy its not a problem) Thanks very much for the response.

Comment: Wait no need, I have it. Thanks very much

Comment: The same result was used in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-n-sqrtnn/28487#28487). It can be derived from [this form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73508/an-exercise-on-liminf-and-limsup/73709#73709) of Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Comment: I presume $\overline\lim$ means $\limsup$?

Comment: Is there an example where the middle equality holds but the other two (or at least one) is strict?

Comment: An example where the middle equality holds but the left inequality is strict would be awesome.

Answer (score 11):

As I mentioned in my comment,

$$a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}= e^{\frac{ \ln (a_n)}{n}} $$

Now, if the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (a_{n+1})-\ln (a_n)}{(n+1)-n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right) $$ exists then by Stolz Cezaro the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \ln (a_n)}{n}$$ exists and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ \ln (a_n)}{n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) $$

The Theorem mentioned in the other post also follows from the stronger version of Stolz Cezaro by exactly the same reasoning.

Comment: Im a bit confused here have you not shown that $\displaystyle \mbox{lim} (a_n)^{(\frac{1}{n})}=\mbox{lim} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: @hmmmm Yep, there is no need for sup limit here.  If $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists then $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ automatically exists and is the same, and this is what I proven... The converse is not true though.....

Answer (score 1):

The equality of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is actually something you already learned in Calculus 1, just in disguise. If we consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x^n$, then the radius of convergence is equal to the first limit by the root test and it is also equal to the second limit by the ratio test, and thus both limits are equal.