# Calculating the limit of $[(2n)!/(n!)^2]^{1/n}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Analysis textbook by Shanti Narayan, is asking to prove the limit
$\lim {\left({\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}\right)}^{1/n} \to \frac{1}{4}$ as $n \to \infty$.
I tried but was unable to find the solution. Even Wolfram Alpha is telling the limit to be $4$.
Please help!

Comment: The limit can't be less than 1, there must be a typo.

Comment: Eric Naslund gives a way to see that the limit is $4$ in a comment at [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99324/how-to-prove-that-lim-frac1n-sqrtnn1n2-2n-frac4e#comment233733_99329).

Comment: @anon I, too, thought so. But I have had no explaination how the question is wrong!

Comment: @Jonas Meyer Thanks! :)

Comment: The central binomial coefficients $\binom{2n}{n}$ are all greater than $1$. Anything greater than $1$ raised to a positive power must likewise be greater than $1$. Hence this limit cannot be less than $1$.

Comment: @anon Thanks! I figured it.

Comment: @gaurav: At that link you will find other methods that can be applied here.  For example, when $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_n \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists, then $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ exists and $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_n \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.  With $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$, this makes it easy to check that the limit is $4$.  You can also make use of $\lim \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=e$, by rewriting it as $\displaystyle4\left(\frac{\sqrt[2n]{(2n)!}}{2n}\right)^2\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)^2$.

Comment: The estimates in [Central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) suffice.

Comment: I meant $\lim \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=1/e$, but actually all you need to know is that $\lim \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$ exists and is nonzero, which is easier.

Comment: related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!^2}
&=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\tag1\\
&=4\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\right)^{1/n}
&=4\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)\right)^{1/n}\tag3\\
&\ge4\left(\frac12\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{1/2}\right)^{1/n}\tag4\\
&=4\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}\right)^{1/n}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(3)$ and inequality $(5)$ give
$$
4\left(\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}\right)^{1/n}\le\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\right)^{1/n}\le4\tag6
$$
and the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\right)^{1/n}=4\tag7
$$

Comment: The terms tend to $1$ but the product itself tends to $0$...

Comment: @anon: but we are taking the geometric mean of terms with a limit... :-)

Comment: @anon: I have fixed the answer up by Squeezing Bernoulli.

Answer (score 16):

A simple proof is based on the observation that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$
 is the central binomial coefficient $\displaystyle{ {2n} \choose n}$.

Look at row $2n$ in the Pascal triangle. The sum of all terms is $2^{2n}= 4^n$ and so ${{2n} \choose n} \le 4^n$. Moreover, the central binomial coefficient is the largest number in that row and so $4^n \le (2n+1){{2n} \choose n}$.
Hence
$$
\frac{4^n}{2n+1} \le {{2n} \choose n} \le 4^n
$$

Since $(2n+1)^{1/n} \to 1$, we conclude that ${{2n} \choose n} ^ {1/n} \to 4$.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: I see now that it's the [same argument](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99324/how-to-prove-that-lim-frac1n-sqrtnn1n2-2n-frac4e#comment233733_99329) used by Eric Naslund as mentioned by Jonas Meyer.

Comment: And I thought my answer used the least background :-) (+1)

Comment: I see how to get $4^n\le(2n+1)\binom{2n}n$ immediately from binomial theorem (I have $2n$ summands, and this is a common bound for all of them.) I do not see immediately $4^n\le(n+1)\binom{2n}n$. What am I missing? (It probably does not matter here that much, but you [linked to this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343243/some-trouble-with-the-induction#comment2731627_1343243) in a question asking about the inequality with $n+1$.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak. fixed, at last.

Answer (score 11):

If you use Stirling's approximation $$n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ then you get $${\left({\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}}\right)}^{1/n} \approx {\left({\dfrac{\sqrt{4 \pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}}\right)}^{1/n} = 4\left(\frac{1}{n\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{2n} \approx 4.$$

It is not difficult to translate this into the language of limits.

Comment: I think it should be $\displaystyle4\left(\frac{1}{n\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}$

Comment: @robjohn: indeed - corrected

Answer (score 4):

As a previous exercise you can prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)=-\int_0^1\ln t\, dt=1.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\ln\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^{1/n} &=\frac{1}{n}\left[ \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \ln k-2\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(n+k)-\ln(k)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right).
\end{align*}$$
Note that in the last equality the second term is a Riemann's sum of $t\mapsto \ln t$ over $[1,2]$. Using \eqref{eq1} we have
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^{1/n} &= -\int_0^1\ln t\, dt+\int_1^2 \ln t\, dt\\
&=1+(-1+\ln 4),
\end{align*}$$
so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^{1/n}=\ln 4.$$ By the continuity of $t\mapsto e^t$ you get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^{1/n}=4.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is really nno meed to use the stirling fomula to calculate this integral, we can just use stolz formula to caluate

$I_{n}=(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)(n!)})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ Using stolz formula we can get $\quad$
$\lim log I_{n}=\lim log(\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1})=log4 $

Comment: The OP don't ask for any integral. Please consider review your answer.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same idea as [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/109835/) cloaked in a $\log$?