# Series Ratio Test Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)!/k!(k+1)!$

Let $a_k = (2k)!/k!(k+1)!$

$\lvert a_{k+1}/a_k\rvert \to 4$ as $k \to \infty$

Thus the series is divergent. Can someone double check ... my gut says it is convergent.

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109829/calculating-the-limit-of-2n-n21-n-as-n-tends-to-infty/110209) if you want to apply the root test.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate.**

Binomial coefficient
$$
\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}
$$
is a positive integer, thus $\ge 1$, so your series is $\ge$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1}
$$
which diverges.

Of course, the middle binomial coefficient is much bigger than $1$, so divergence is much worse than the harmonic series.

Comment: Some simple bounds for the central binomial coefficient appear in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

conducting the Ratio test:

You series is $$\frac{2k!}{k!(k+1)!}$$

Now, $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!(k+2)!}}{\frac{2k!}{k!(k+1)!}}$$

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!(k+2)!}*\frac{k!(k+1)!}{2k!}$$
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k!(2k+2)!}{(2k)!(k+2)!}$$
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2k+1)*(2k+2)}{(k+1)*(k+2)}$$
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2k+1)*(2k+2)}{(k+1)*(k+2)} = 4$$

You are correct.