# Prove by induction: $\frac{2^{2n}}{n+1}<\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2},n>1$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction: $\frac{2^{2n}}{n+1}<\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2},n>1$

For $n=2$ equality holds.

For $n=k$

$$\frac{2^{2k}}{k+1}<\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$$

For $n=k+1$

$$\frac{2^{2k+2}}{k+2}<\frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}$$

How to prove this?

Comment: m! is (m - 2)! * (m - 1) * m, maybe that will help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343243/some-trouble-with-the-induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^{2n+2}}{k+2}&=\frac{2^{2n}}{k+1}\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}\\\\
&<\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}\right)\left(\frac{4(k+1)(k+1)^2}{(k+2)(2k+2)(2k+1)}\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}\right)\left(\frac{2(k+1)^2}{(k+2)(2k+1)}\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}\right)\left(\frac{2k^2+4k+4}{2k^2+5k+2}\right)\\\\
&<\frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}
\end{align}$$

for $k\ge 2$, as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that: $$\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}\leq \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$

or, equivalently:

$$2(k+1)^2\leq (2k+1)(k+2)$$