# How to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\left\{(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(2n+n)\right\}^{1/n}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, radicals

If
$\displaystyle f(n)=\frac1n\Big\{(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(2n+n)\Big\}^{1/n}$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ equals:
$$
\begin{array}{}
(\mathrm{A})\ \frac4e\qquad&(\mathrm{B})\ \frac{27}{4e}\qquad&(\mathrm{C})\ \frac{27e}{4}\qquad&(\mathrm{D})\ 4e
\end{array}
$$
I couldn't get the right way to start off with this problem. But, as the options include the constant $e$ I think I will have to work out with logarithms.

So, this is what I did. 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\\
=\mathrm{exp}\left(\ln\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\right)\right)\\
=\mathrm{exp}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\ln\left(f(b)\right)\right]\right)\\
=\mathrm{exp}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\ln(2n+1)+\ln(2n+2)+\ldots+\ln(2n+n)\right)\right]\right)
$$
I'm not able to proceed further. In case my method is correct please give me hints on proceeding further and in case it is wrong give me the same on another method.

Comment: Your expression for $\log f(n)$ is incorrect, should be $$\log(1/n)+(1/n)\log(\dots)$$

Comment: Which is $f(n)$ supposed to be?
$$
\frac1n\left\{\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n+n)}\right\}^{1/n}
$$
or
$$
\frac1n\left\{(2n+1)(2n+2)-(2n+n)\right\}^{1/n}
$$

Comment: Oh, I see, it is an extended product.

Comment: latex anyone please ?

Comment: @Arjang: I was already doing it, thus my question :-)

Comment: Similar problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99324/how-to-prove-that-lim-frac1n-sqrtnn1n2-2n-frac4e

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As there are $n$ terms as the multipliers,

$$\displaystyle f(n)=\frac1n\Big\{(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(2n+n)\Big\}^{1/n}=\left(\prod_{1\le r\le n}\frac{2n+r}n\right)^{\frac1n}$$

hence
$$\ln f(n)=\frac1n\sum_{1\le r\le n}\ln\left(2+\frac rn\right)$$
Using
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n g\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1g(x)dx,$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln f(n)=\int_0^1\ln(x+2)dx$$

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\ln(x+2)dx&=&x\ln(x+2)-\int\frac x{x+2}dx\\
&=& x\ln(x+2)-\int\frac{x+2-2}{x+2}dx\\
&=& x\ln(x+2)-\int\ dx+2\int\frac1{x+2}dx\\
&=& x\ln(x+2)-x+2\ln(x+2)\\
&=&(x+2)\ln(x+2)-x
\end{eqnarray}
hence
$$\int_0^1\ln(x+2)dx=3\ln3-1-\{2\ln2-0\}=\ln (3^3)-\ln e-\ln(2^2)=\ln \frac{27}{4e}$$

Comment: What about the power '1/n' of the whole series in the question?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, as $\ln (a^m)=m\ln a$

Comment: Sir, but in the question itself there is one 1/n.......so taking log and applying above rule would make it 1/n^2......

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, as there are $n$ terms as the multipliers, $$\displaystyle f(n)=\frac1n\Big\{(2n+1)(2n+2)\cdots(2n+n)\Big\}^{1/n}=\left(\prod_{1\le r\le n}\frac{2n+r}n\right)^{\frac1n}$$ Now apply log wrt $e$

Comment: Ohhh.....now I get it sir....thank you for your answer.....

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, my pleasure. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Hint (for this multiple choice question): $2 \le f(n) \le 3$.

Comment: Hah, multiple choice does make this problem easier, I guess. :)

Comment: njguliyev how you get $2 \leq f(n)\leq 3,$ explain me , thanks

Answer (score 8):

$$\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}\sim\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{3n}{e}\right)^{3n}\sqrt{6\pi n}}{\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\left[\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\frac{27^n}{4^n}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}\to \frac{27}{4e}$$

Answer (score 3):

We can express $f(n)=\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ for
$$a_n=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)\dots(2n+n)}{n^n}.$$
Let us check whether the sequence $a_{n+1}/a_n$ has a limit. 
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\\
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)} \cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\\
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)} \cdot \frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}
\end{align*}
From this we see that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{27}{4e}.$$

Now if this limit exists, then the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ also exists and has the same value. See:

- [Limit of ${a_n}^{1/n}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n)
- [Inequality involving $\limsup$ and $\liminf$: $ \liminf(a_{n+1}/a_n) \le \liminf((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup(a_{n+1}/a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf)