# solve for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(3n)!(1/27)^n}{(n!)^3}$

Tags: limits, factorial

I believe the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(3n)!(1/27)^n}{(n!)^3}$ -> 0.

But I am not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Because there is a higher power in the denomination that the numerator, the limit goes to 0?

Comment: Maybe not strictly a duplicate, but closely related to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769570/find-lim-n-to-infty-left-frac33nn33n-right1-n

Comment: yes, it goes to zero, because acctually you have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n!)^2(27)^{n-1}}$

Comment: @Fernando: careful...

Comment: You are right, I made terrible mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Use Stirling's approximation
$$
n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n 
$$
for large $n$ to write
$$
\frac{(3n)!(1/27)^n}{(n!)^3}\sim\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 3 n} (3n/e)^{3n} (1/27)^n }{(\sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n)^3 }=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2n\pi}\to 0
$$
for large $n$.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without the stirling approximation?

Comment: @Jacob: I give a way below, just using limit laws.

Comment: For $n\geq 2$ we have $\int_{n-1}^n\log x\; dx<$ $\log n< $ $\int_n^{n+1}\log x\;dx.$  So $n(\log n)-n+1=$ $\int_1^n\log x\;dx<$ $\log n!$ $<\int_2^{n+1}\log x\; dx=$ $(n+1)\log (n+1)-n+1-2\log 2$ which is cruder than Stirling but ought to work for this Q.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(3n)! (1/27)^n}{(n!)^3} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(3n)!}{(3^n n!)^3}$$
Let's solve it with a ram. It's obvious that $1 < (3n)! < 3^{3n} * n^n $ and $n^n < n! n!$ so we can use the Squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(3^n n!)^3} = 0; \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^{3n} * n^n}{(3^{n} n!)^3} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(n!)^3} = 0 $$