# Why is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality

Why is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$$

if :
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n} = 0 \implies n^n >n! \quad\text{for "big" n}$$

I don't understand it.

Comment: $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sqrt [n] {n^n} =\infty$

Comment: @DougM I fixed it.

Comment: $n^n > n!$ always. No fancy limit argument needed. And the $n$th root of $n^n$ is just $n$.

Comment: But $\sqrt[n]{n^n}\to\infty$ as well, so $n^n>n!$ proves nothing about the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n!}$.

Comment: If $f(n) \geq g(n) \geq 0$, then $f(n) \to 0$ implies that $g(n) \to 0$. However, it is not true that $f(n) \to \infty$ implies that $g(n) \to \infty.$

Comment: I thought that any exponent less than $n$ gives the limit of n-th root equal to $1$

Comment: It is true that $n! > (n/e)^n$. Might be easier to show that $ n! > (n/3)^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n = n!$.

The limit $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is related to the root test for series convergence.
In this context, it is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf) that if $\lim \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ and they are equal. Let's compute the ratios then:
$$
\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim (n+1) = \infty
$$
Therefore, $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}= \infty$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769591/589