# Computing $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\left((n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)\right)^{\frac1n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, riemann-sum

The question asks to find the following limit.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{\left((n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)\right)^{1/n}}{n}\right]$$

I tried taking $\log$ but I do not think that we get an L' Hopital form after that.

There is another approach that I tried. I rewrote the expression as
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n+2}{n}...\frac{n+n}{n}\right)^{1/n}\right]$$

If I take $\log$ now, won't the limit be 0? The answer in my book is $4/e$.

Comment: Stuck in L'H pit... Hint: Rewrite the ratio using factorials.

Comment: Did what after $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$ ? Thanks

Comment: Stirling's formula cleans it up, but I liked your interpretation as a Riemann sum. +1

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475786/how-to-compute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-left-2n12n2-cdots2nn

Comment: I am pretty sure this has been asked *many* times before. Do you mind helping me in finding an exact duplicate?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Indeed I have been searching for those post but I did not find out .

Answer (score 2):

Take logarithm and you get a Riemann sum for

$$\ln(S)=\int_0^1\ln(1+x)dx$$

Which on evaluation yields 
$$\ln(S)=2\ln(2)-1$$

Comment: so the answer isn't 4/e?

Comment: Of course it is. Apply exp to both sides.

Comment: Ya forgot abt that. Got it now.

Comment: What do you mean "It's a Riemann sum."? Better to say "Take the logarithm. The resulting expression is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1\ln (1+x)\, dx.$"

Comment: Yes I mean that only

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{\left((n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)\right)^{1/n}}{n}=\left[\frac{(2n)!}{ n^nn!}\right]^{\frac1n}=a_n^\frac1n$$

and by [ratio-root criteria](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335500/do-the-sequences-from-the-ratio-and-root-tests-converge-to-the-same-limit) $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rightarrow L\implies a_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow L$$

we have

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{ (n+1)^{n+1}(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n^nn!}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\to \frac4e$$

therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{\left((n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)\right)^{1/n}}{n}\right]=\frac4e$$

Answer (score 1):

By Riemann sum we have $$\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n+2}{n}...\frac{n+n}{n}\right)^{1/n}\right] =\exp\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right)\right] \to \exp\left[\int_0^1 \ln\left(1+x\right)dx\right] \\= \exp\left[ 2\ln2 -1\right] =\color{red}{\frac{4}{e}} $$

since $$((x+1)\ln(x+1) -(x+1))' =\ln(x+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another idea: take $\log$ and apply [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
\log L =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1) + \cdots + \log(n+n) - n\log n}{n} = \cdots
$$