# I need help to advance in the resolution of that limit: $ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}} $

Tags: limits, factorial, radicals

how I can continue this limit resolution?

The limit is:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}} $$

This is that I have done:

I apply this test: $ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} $

Operating and simplifying I arrive to this point:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}} $$

I've done something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I am also not sure, if this limit test + "all operations and simplifying" works  in all cases. I can't follow the steps.

Comment: As written, your (starting) statement is wrong; you need to write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ in the RHS, not just the ratio. Also, note that the equality only holds **if** both limits exist -- the LHS could have a limit, but not the RHS (although the converse cannot happen). [See for instance this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335500/do-the-sequences-from-the-ratio-and-root-tests-converge-to-the-same-limit)

Comment: For various approaches to this limit, see also [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/28476). (But probably this is not a duplicate, since the question here seems to be mainly about the approach provided in the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)^n = \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n} \to1/e$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

*For reference, another approach starting from scratch:*

Using the fact that $\ln n! = n\ln n - n +o(n)$ (see e.g. [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489796/75808) of it), we can rewrite the quantities considered in the exponential form (almost always helpful) to obtain that
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{n!}{n^n}}
= e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k - n\ln n\right)}
= e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(n\ln n - n +o(n) - n\ln n\right)}
= e^{\frac{1}{n}\left(- n +o(n)\right)}
= e^{-1 +o(1)}
$$
so the limit is $e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{n!}{n^n}}$

$\ln A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\dfrac rn$

Like [The limit of a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k), this equals to $$\int_0^1\ln x\ dx$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Observe that
$$\frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{n + 1 - 1}{n + 1} = 1 - \frac1{n + 1}$$

Now rewrite the limit argument as $\exp(\ln \cdot)$...

Answer (score 3):

By Stirling approximation as $n\to \infty$ we have
$$
\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}\sim \left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{(n/e)^n}{n^n}\right)^{1/n} \sim \frac{1}{e}(2\pi n)^{1/2n} \to e^{-1}.
$$

As pointed out by Clement, one should justify why one can take the limit directly inside; the reason is that for any $x< 1<y$ one have definitively
$$
xe^{-1}n^{1/2n}\le \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}\le ye^{-1}n^{1/2n}.
$$
Since $n^{1/2n}\to 1$ and the above inequality holds for all choices of $x$, $y$, we conclude as above :)

Comment: That requires a bit more detailing, I'd say: taking powers of equivalents (when the power depends on $n$) is delicate and can be misleading, and writing down the exponential form and what the equivalent actually means is a safe way to avoid mistakes. (For instance, $1\sim 1+\frac{1}{n}$, yet $1=1^n \not\sim (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$).

Comment: Oh, Clement, I see your point, you are right :)

Comment: Yep :) I am editing it

Answer (score 2):

HINT
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$