# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{{n!}^{1/n}\}/n$

Tags: limits, factorial, radicals

Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\{{(n!)}^{1/n}\}/n$$

I took exp log but getting answer as 1 but it should be 1/e. Required a nice approach.

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @Argon No I have not heard it

Comment: Stirling's approximation:$$n!\sim\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$This version should suffice :-) Or to be more accurate,$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598508/i-need-help-to-advance-in-the-resolution-of-that-limit-lim-n-to-infty-s?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Perfect and thanks!

Comment: See also [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/28476).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $n$, we have $n! \simeq \exp (n \log n - n)$, Taking the limit then gives  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{{(n!)}^{1/n}/n\} = \frac1 e$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Evaluate an assymptotical equivalent to $$n!^{1/n} = e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)/n}$$
by first finding one of $$\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)\over n$$