# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\left[\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right).....\left(n+n\right)}{n^{n}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

> **Question**: Evaluate lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\left[\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right).....\left(n+n\right)}{n^{n}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$

**My Approach** Let $a_{n}=\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right).....\left(n+n\right)}{n^{n}}$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right).....\left(2n+2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{4}{\exp (1)}$$

**Using Cauchy's second theorem On Limits**

Lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}\frac{a_{3}}{a_{2}}..........\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$=Lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\left[\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{1}}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{4}{\exp(1)}$

Now I don't know how to move forward

Comment: You are almost done. Just fix the use of Cauchy theorem and say that using Cauchy's theorem we have $\lim a_n^{1/n}=\lim (a_{n+1}/a_n)=4/e$

Comment: I think he made a typo and went ahead with it. The integral needed is $\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x)\,dx$

Comment: Also you need to write $e$ or $\exp(1)$ instead of $\exp$.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475786/how-to-compute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-left-2n12n2-cdots2nn and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598508/i-need-help-to-advance-in-the-resolution-of-that-limit-lim-n-to-infty-s

Comment: You just solved your own question

Comment: @Rick Almost! Still now .i just don't how to prove 
lim $\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$=lim$\left(a_{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right]^{1/n}&=&\exp\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\\&=&\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x)\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{4}{e}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Answer (score 3):

Let the limit be $L$ then:

$$\begin{align}
\ln(L) &=  \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln\left( 1 + \frac{i}{n} \right) \\
 &= \int_{0}^{1}\ln( 1+x ) dx \\
 &= (x+1)\ln(1+x) -x |_{0}^{1} \\
 &= 2\ln(2) - 1
\end{align}$$

So the required limit is $\exp({2\ln (2) -1}) = \color{blue}{\dfrac{4}{e}}$

Comment: It's a typo I guess. You forgot the logs. You need integral of $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: @paramanandSingh Ah yes forgot to put the log! Thanks

Comment: Ok my +1 delivered to you.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have a similar question which I post here: [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587461/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-sum-r-1n-fracrn2nr). Thank you for thoughts :)