# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n} $

Tags: limits

> Find
>   $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n}     \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n}.$$

I tried with ln composition but ineffectively.  Any idea?

Comment: Try to use integrals.

Comment: Use Cesaro-Stolz and try to find limit of $b_{n+1}/b_n$ where $b_n=a_n^n$ and $a_n$ is given sequence in question.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg 
I know that it is possible but didn't see how at school yet. But if you can explain it I d learn with pleasure :)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598508/i-need-help-to-advance-in-the-resolution-of-that-limit-lim-n-to-infty-s/1598524#1598524 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475786/how-to-compute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n-left-2n12n2-cdots2nn/475791#475791

Comment: $\ln\left( \prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n}\right)=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\ln\left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)$
which is a Riemann sum of $\int_0^2\ln(1+x)dx$.

Comment: i find one half of the integral between 1 and 1,5 of ln(t). Is it this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n}&=
\frac{1}{n^2} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(n+ k)\right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{(3n)!}{n!}\right)^{1/n}\\&\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{(3n)^{3n}\sqrt{2\pi (3n)}}{e^{3n}}\cdot
\frac{e^{n}}{n^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{3^3}{e^2}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/n}\to\frac{27}{e^2}\end{align} $$
where we used the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorials.

Comment: how do you show the first equality please :)?

Comment: We have that $\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{n^2} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(n+ k)\right)^{1/n}$.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Any further doubt?

Comment: that s okay thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Following the suggestion by [Paramanand Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh) let indicate

$$a_n=\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)^{1/n}=\sqrt[n] b_n \quad b_n=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}     \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)$$
then

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n+2} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n+1} \right)}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \left(1+ \frac{ k}{n} \right)}=\left(1+\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\right)\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{n(n+k+1)}{(n+1)(n+k)} $$

$$=\left(1+\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\right)\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\right)\frac{n^{2n}(3n+1)}{(n+1)^{2n}(n+1)} \to 3\cdot 3\cdot \frac{3}{e^2}=\frac{27}{e^2}$$

and therefore (see [Limit of ${a_n}^{1/n}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-a-n1-n-is-equal-to-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-a-n))

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n] b_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{27}{e^2}$$

Comment: interesting method thank you !

Comment: @MarineGalantin You are welcome, I've only write down a solution following the method indicated by Paramanand Singh. Indeed it is very useful when you deal with sequences like $\sqrt[n] {a_n}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Compute the limit of the logarithm, noticing that

$$\log\biggl(\prod_{k+1}^{2n}\Bigl(1+\frac kn\Bigr)^{\tfrac1n}\biggr)=\sum_{k+1}^{2n}\frac1n\log\Bigl(1+\frac kn\Bigr).$$
Looks very much like an *upper Riemann sum*.

Comment: actually i don't know this method yet. If we can find something else ? I can't use it in the frame of my lessons.

Nevertheless, I ve done it, i find the integral between 1 and 1,5 of ln(t). Is it this ?

Comment: I find twice the integral between $1$ and $3$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes you're right ! however it doesn't give the good result :( approximatively 2.6 in spite of 3.6

Comment: For the log? How do you find ca $3.6$?

Comment: no the problem was i found 1.28 and when you take back the exp you find 3.6. So now the problem is solved :)