# How I can find limit of a given problem: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n[(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+n)]^{\frac 1n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is the limit ?

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}[(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+n)]^{\displaystyle\frac {1} {n}}$$

The given answer is $\displaystyle\frac{4}{e}$, but I don't know how to find it or which formula is applicable here.Please help.

Thanks for  help.

Comment: any restrictions like Taylor series?

Comment: Bring the $1/n$ inside, get $[(1+1/n)(1+2/n)\cdots(1+n/n)]^{1/n}$. Take the log and recognize a Riemann sum.

Comment: Also duplicate to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115562/115115 from 1 year ago and certainly many others

Comment: Here's a another way to do it: This limit equals $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\binom{2n}{n} \frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}$$and $\frac{1}{2n+1}4^{n}\leq \binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^{n},$ so we see that the limit equals $$4 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{4}{e}$$ by Sterling's approximation.

Comment: See also: [How to prove that $\lim \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)... 2n} = \frac{4}{e}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99324) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/99324).