# Calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty }{\frac{{[n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1)]}^\frac1n}n}$ using Riemann sum

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

I want to calculate

$  \lim_{n \to \infty }{\frac{{[n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1)]}^\frac1n}n} $

using

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}n\right)$$

I know I have to convert $\frac nk$ to $x$, but I am confused since all the factors are multiplied together. Should I use $\log$?

Comment: You should show whatever you have tried so that people might address your problem more accurately.

Comment: Indeed you should use $\log$. Before that, though, I think you should factor out an $n$ from each term in the numerator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {[(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)]^{1/n}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115562/evaluate-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac-n1n2-cdotsnn1-nn) (The accepted answer is using riemann sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{[n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1)]}^{1/n}}n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[1\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac2n\right)\cdots\left(2-\frac1n\right)\right]}^{1/n}\\
&=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac kn\right)\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\int_0^1\log(1+x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
\end{align}
$$