# Limit of the sequence $x_n= \frac{[(a+1)(a+2)...(a+n)]^{1/n}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Limit of the sequence    $$ x_n= \frac{[(a+1)(a+2)...(a+n)]^{1/n}}{n}.$$ where $a$ is a fixed positive real number.

I want to find the limit of the sequence . I tried to apply Cauchy limit theorem. But I failed. How to find the limit of this sequence

Comment: Any conditions on $a$?

Comment: sorry, a is fixed positive real number

Comment: Intuitively, taking $a$ to be integer, the product is the factorial of $n+a$ over $a!$. Taking the $n^{th}$ root, $a!$ vanishes and using the Stirling approximation we are left with $(a+n)/ne$ which converges to $1/e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logs and apply [Stolz Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Indeed
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n(a+k)^{1/n} 
$$
so
$$
\log x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(a+k)
$$
whence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \log x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(a+n+1)}{2n+1}
$$
a limit that you should be able to compute.

Comment: Shouldn't the expression for the logarithm be $\log x_n=-\log n+\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(a+k) =\frac{-n\log n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(a+k)}n$. (Still, Stolz-Cesaro theorem can help here - similar as in the [linked posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3098736).)

Comment: Your answer is not correct (you get $\log x_n \to 0$, $x_n \to 1$). Why don't you fix it (as Martin pointed out) so that future readers are not misled by a wrong accepted answer?

Answer (score 5):

One can proceed similarly as in [Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {[(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)]^{1/n}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115562/evaluate-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac-n1n2-cdotsnn1-nn/1115564#1115564): Use that 
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
*if* all $a_n$ are positive and *if* the limit on the right-hand side exists. (See for example [Limit of ${a_n}^{1/n}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-a-n1-n-is-equal-to-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-a-n).)

Here
$$
a_n = \frac{(a+1)\ldots (a+n)}{n^n}
$$
and
$$
 \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(a+n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
 = \frac{a+n+1}{n+1} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n \to \frac 1e \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and Gamma function you have:
$$
\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {a + k} \right)}  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {a + 1 + k} \right)}  = \left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} }
  = {{\Gamma \left( {a + 1 + n} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {a + 1} \right)}}
$$

By the Stirling approximation we have
$$
z^{\,\overline {\,w\,} }  \propto {{\sqrt {2\,\pi } } \over {\Gamma (z)}}e^{\, - \,w} w^{\,z + w - 1/2} \left( {1 + O\left( {{1 \over w}} \right)} \right)
 \quad \left| \matrix{ \;\left| w \right| \to \infty  \hfill \cr   \;\left| {\arg (z + w)} \right| < \pi  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

So
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over n}\left( {\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \right)^{\,1/n}  \propto \left( {{{\sqrt {2\,\pi } } \over {\Gamma (a + 1)}}} \right)^{\,1/n} e^{\, - \,1} \;n^{\,{{a + 1/2} \over n}} \left( {1 + O\left( {{1 \over n}} \right)} \right)^{\,1/n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{\sqrt {2\,\pi } } \over {\Gamma (a + 1)}}} \right)^{\,1/n} e^{\, - \,1 + \left( {{{a + 1/2} \over n}} \right)\;\ln n} \left( {1 + O\left( {{1 \over n}} \right)} \right)^{\,1/n}  \cr} 
$$

and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } {1 \over n}\left( {\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \right)^{1/n}  = 1/e
$$