An analysis question about limits and sequences
I'm having a hard time proving:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}= \frac{4}{e}$
any tips?
The book I found this exercise in says I should use the following property:
If a sequence $a_n$ has only strictly positive terms and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=a$


Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99324/42969 and the linked questions.

The first factor $1/2$ should probably be $1/n$.

Yes, it seems the book got it wrong, thank you for the help

A search with Approach0 shows that this has been asked and answered several times

Well, in my defense, the book has stated the problem, not me, I'll add a photo

But I found this tool approach0 very useful, I intend to use it in the future, thank you very much

I am voting to close this post as a(n erroneous) duplicate of How to prove that $\lim \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)... 2n} = \frac{4}{e}$
