# A series with infinitely many logarithms: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\ln 2}2+\frac{\ln 3}3+\cdots + \frac{\ln n}n \right)^{\frac1n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

I have to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\ln 3}{3}+\cdots + \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I'm just curious if there is a simple way to solve it. I think I solved it by using some pretty unusual trick: I just considered the sum approximation under the radical by using an integral and got $\approx \frac{\ln^{2}n}{2}$. Then I simply applied Cauchy D'Alembert and got 1. Still thinking of a simple way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each (sufficiently large) $n$, $$1< \left(\frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\ln 3}{3}+\cdots + \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{1/n}<(1+1+\cdots+1)^{1/n}=(n-1)^{1/n}<n^{1/n}.$$

By using (or proving) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$ it is easy to finish.  (By Cauchy--D'Alembert, I'm guessing you mean something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n).)

Comment: Yes. This is a really short/elementary proof. Nice! Thanks :-)

Comment: @jonas: why community wiki

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: it's clear.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I see you're using strict inequalities. This means that 1<1, which I don't think makes this proof valid.

Comment: @Ray: The inequalities all apply for each particular (big enough) number $n$. Strict inequality is true.  For example, $n-1<n$ is true.  But if $a_n<b_n<c_n$ for all (big enough) $n$, and if $\lim a_n = L=\lim c_n$, then $\lim b_n = L$.  This is more generally true if $a_n\leq b_n\leq c_n$.  Recall that strict inequalities of terms do not typically carry over into strict inequalities of limits.  For another example, $1/n>0$ for all $n>0$, but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1/n=0$.  (This is related to the fact that closed intervals are closed, but open intervals are usually not.)

Comment: Good explanation; I'll buy it :)

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: One possible advantage is that it is welcoming to other contributors who may want to add something to the answer.

Comment: @Jonas: Emm, ok

Answer (score 3):

We use $\log(t+1)\leq t$ for $t\geq 0$. We have 
$$a_n:=\frac 1n\log \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln k}k\right)=\frac 1n\log \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln k}k-1\right)\leq \frac 1n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln k}k-1\right).$$
Since $\frac{\ln n}n\to 0$, the Cesaro means converge to $0$ (use $\varepsilon$) hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac 1n\log \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln k}k\right)=0$ and the limit of $e^{a_n}$ is $1$.