# Limit of the sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n)

I know that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$$

and I can imagine that $n$ grows linearly while $n$th root compresses it exponentially and therefore the result is $1$, but how do I calculate it?

Comment: Look at the limit of the logarithm instead: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ln n$. What’s $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}x$?

Comment: So the "trick" is $$a^b=e^{b*\ln{a}}$$

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Perhaps one of the most elementary ways to prove it: since $\,n\geq 1\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\,$ , we can put$$\sqrt[n]{n}=1+c_n\,,\,c_n\geq0\Longrightarrow n=(1+c_n)^n\geq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}c_n^2$$using the binomial expansion ,so that$$0<c_n\leq\sqrt\frac{2}{n-1}$$and now just apply the squeeze theorem and get $\,c_n\to 0\,$, which is precisely what we need.

Comment: what is this cn??

Comment: It's a number $>0$ that depends on $n$.

Comment: @experimentX: Specifically, $c_n$ by definition is $\sqrt[n]{n}-1$.  It is a case of introducing notation to make the exposition easier.

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]n$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}$$
and as we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0$ {apply  l'Hospital's rule}
So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$$

Answer (score 6):

Claim: For each $a>1$, there exists $N$ such that $n<a^n$ for all $n>N$.

Proof: Write $a=1+b$.  By the binomial theorem, $a^n=(1+b)^n\geq \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)b^2$ when $n\geq 2$.  Thus $\frac{a^n}{n} \geq \frac{1}{2}(n-1)b^2$.  It follows that if $N$ is at least $2/b^2+1$, then when $n>N$, $n<a^n$.

---

As a consequence, for each $a>1$, there exists $N$ such that $1\leq n^{1/n}<a$ for all $n>N$, and this implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$.

Comment: [DonAntonio's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/154188) is simpler.

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing it. One of the things I've never forgotten since my late prof. in $1$st undergraduate year taught us this proof: I think I drooled for a while completely fascinated for the simplicity of the proof, compared with what several books showed.

Comment: @DonAntonio:  Inspired by your post I cleaned mine up a little (but didn't essentially change the method).

Answer (score 5):

One could use the fact that for a sequence of positive terms, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n\of {a_n}$ and the two limits are equal. A proof of this general fact can be found in [these notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20130728110356/http://math.uga.edu/~pete/243series4.pdf) of Pete L. Clark. This result can also be found in many analysis texts; e.g., baby Rudin.

That your sequence has limit $1$ is easily shown using the above fact. A detailed proof that your sequence has limit $1$, based on the proof of the above fact,  can be found in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822).

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn/28487#28487) and
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/76800/) for the result on relation between $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.

Comment: The linked text later became a part of the notes on [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220503044808/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

Let's see a very elementary proof. Without loss of generality we proceed replacing $n$ by $2^n$ and get that:
$$ 1\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {2^n}^{\frac{1}{{2}^{n}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {2}^{\frac{n}{{2}^{n}}}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {2}^{\frac{n}{\dbinom{n}{2}}}=2^0=1$$

By Squeeze Theorem the proof is complete.

Comment: what did you do near the last step??

Comment: @experimentX:  consider the fact that $2^n$ is the sum of binomial coefficients for given n. Then you take all all the terms away except that one and get an useful inequality. See here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n

Comment: I understand that ... thanks !!

Comment: @experimentX: you're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Let$$y=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ 
$$\log y=\log( n^{\frac{1}{n}})$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\log y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}$$
We have $\left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right)$ form so we apply L'hospital rule, we get,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\log y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1}$$
$$\therefore \lim_{n\to\infty}\log y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} y=e^{0}=1.$$
It follows that, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$