# Better way to do $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n-1)^{1/n}}{{\sqrt{2}}^{1/n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n-1)^{1/n}}{{\sqrt{2}}}$$

because im trying to prove the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3n-1}{(\sqrt{2})^{n}}$$

by the n-th root test.

Wolfram Alpha gives me a step by step solution that involves L'Hopital's Rule but Im not allowed to use it yet. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't want a power in the denominator. Then you can take logs and show it. The ratio test is easier anyway.

Comment: @Asvin but that what wolfram says, then it uses l'hospital

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I'm sure W|A tests for $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{\sqrt 2} \sqrt[n]{3n-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the root test doesn't seem the best way: the ratio test requires
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n+2}{(\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}\frac{(\sqrt{2})^n}{3n-1}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1
$$

For the root test: you need
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n-1)^{1/n}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
So you just need the limit of the numerator and taking the logarithm brings you to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(3n-1)}{n}=0
$$
Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(3n-1)^{1/n}=e^0=1$.

Why is that limit zero? Compute instead
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(3x-1)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(3x-1)}{3x-1}\frac{3x-1}{x}
$$
The second factor has limit $3$. For the first do the change of variables $3x-1=e^t$, so you get
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^t}
$$
which you should know is zero.

Answer (score 0):

By noticing that
$$\sqrt[3n-1]{3n-1} \le \sqrt[n]{3n-1} \le \sqrt[n]{3n} = \sqrt[n]3 \sqrt[n]n$$
and using the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]n=1$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154163/limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1) we get that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{3n-1} = 1.$$

Hence
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{3n-1}}{\sqrt2} = \frac1{\sqrt2}.$$