# Show that $\limsup|s_n|^{1\over n}\le \limsup|{s_{n+1}\over s_n}|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inequality involving $\limsup$ and $\liminf$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf)
>   [limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n)

Show that $\limsup|s_n|^{1\over n}\le \limsup|{s_{n+1}\over s_n}|$ and similarly $\liminf|s_n|^{1\over n}\ge \liminf|{s_{n+1}\over s_n}|$.
I have no idea where to start. I tried to show the inequality through subsequence but still don't quite get where to start. Any explaination how to link to the concept of related topic would be appreciated.

Comment: This inequality appeared in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn/28487#28487) and [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n/76800#76800). See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: How did you find those answers? Good memory or good search technique (or both, of course)? I have had limited success (read basically none) with searches for common terms such as $\limsup$.

Comment: @copper.hat When I first saw this inequality at MSE, it was new to me and it seemed interesting, so I noted down the link. Later I added a few other links. Perhaps the next time searching will be easier, since I've added tags [limsup+inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup+inequality) to that question. (There are probably a few other questions which would deserve these tags, too.)

Comment: Anyway, if I wanted to search for similar questions, this Google search seems promising: [limsup frac site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/#q=limsup+frac+site:math.stackexchange.com). Some tips and tricks for searching MSE can be found at meta in [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-do-you-search-for-duplicates) and other question tagged [search](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a start for you.

For convenience we may suppose that the $s_n$ are non-negative and omit the absolute value signs. Suppose that $$\limsup_ns_n^{1\over n}>\limsup_n\,{s_{n+1}\over s_n}\;.$$ Let $$b=\frac12\left(\limsup_ns_n^{1\over n}+\limsup_n\,{s_{n+1}\over s_n}\right)\;;$$ then there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}<b$$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Thus, for all $n>n_0$ we have $s_n<s_{n_0}b^{n-n_0}$. Let $a=s_{n_0}b^{-n_0}$, so that $s_n<ab^n$ for $n>n_0$. Then $s_n^{1/n}<a^{1/n}b$ for $n>n_0$.

1. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}$?
2. How does $b$ compare with $\limsup\limits_n\,s_n^{1/n}$?