# How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1 \rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] a_n=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let $a_n\geq0$
>
> Prove/disprove:  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1 \rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] a_n=1$$

*Proof:* By definition a sequence $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] b_n=L$ iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=L$ since  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1$  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] a_n=1$

Am I right?

Comment: Is $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @user60887 Yes, Sorry I will add it

Comment: Why should $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{b_n} = L \iff \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = L$ be true "by definition" (if at all)?

Comment: I think he is using the ratio test.

Comment: @dalastboss I do not know the name but it is as describe here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n

Comment: If that is a result you may use in this context, I agree the proof follows from your argument modulo a few details. For example, it is also probably worth showing that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1 \implies \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$. This should only require a couple lines of justification using limit rules, and also be careful to explain why it is safe to divide $a_n$.

Comment: consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^{1/n}$

Comment: yoyo, that limit goes to 1, as does the ratio of successive terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see where does the fact you use come from (certainly not from the definition). From the [link you provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76800/131872) it seems at least the "if" part is true, so I guess you can prove it like that.

But there's also a quick and easy way to see it:
\begin{align*}1\le\sqrt[n]x\le x&\text{ if }x\ge1\\1\ge\sqrt[n]x\ge x&\text{ if }x\le1\end{align*}
Therefore $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to1$ because all its members are closer to $1$ than in the original sequence.

Comment: In other words, it follows from the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @GregMartin It follows directly from the definition. One could somehow apply the squeeze theorem ($1\pm|1-a_n|$?), but it seems a little bit forced to me.

Comment: The Squeeze Theorem can be applied with the three sequences $\min\{1,a_n\}$, $\{\sqrt[n]{a_n}\}$, $\max\{1,a_n\}$ - doesn't seem that forced to me. And "all its members are closer to 1 than in the original sequence" is an intuitive idea (a good one), the rigorous realization of which is in fact this application of the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @GregMartin The "intuitive idea" is exactly in the definition of a limit! The sentence you quote says $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}-1|\le |a_n-1|$, so from the convergence of $a_n$ we get $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists n_0\forall n\ge n_0, |\sqrt[n]{a_n}-1|\le |a_n-1|<\varepsilon$, which is the convergence of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.

Comment: - which is the proof of the Squeeze Theorem! :) I feel like we're arguing the same side here....

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced by your proof; even if it's true, it's certainly not 'by definition'.

This problem a bit easier to think about if you take logarithms. The statement is equivalent to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a'_n = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} a'_n = 0$$
where $a'_n=\log a_n$.

Hopefully you can convince yourself that this is true, prove the above statement, and then take exponentials and deduce (from continuity of $\exp$) the result you seek.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about the implications and how you phrase things. You use a result, this is not "by definition" and the result you quote also proves just one implication, not an equivalence. You could state things like this:

> We know that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=L$ and $b_n > 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] b_n=L$.
>
> Since  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ and  $a_n >0$ for all sufficiently  large $n$,  and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] a_n=1$.

*Commentary:* This assumes you are free to use the result you quoted so that the "We know" is justified. Otherwise use an approach from other answers, or prove the result you use too.

Comment: This is also in a comment. But I think it should be an answer too.

Comment: He could use the approach from other answers, or he could prove the lemma...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's quite true. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Observe that: $|\sqrt[n]{a_n} - 1| = \dfrac{|a_n-1|}{|(\sqrt[n]{a_n})^{n-1} + (\sqrt[n]{a_n})^{n-2}+\cdots +\sqrt[n]{a_n}+1|} < |a_n-1|$. This implies the answer.

Comment: $|\sqrt[n]{a_n} - 1| = \dfrac{|a_n-1|}{|(\sqrt[n]{a_n})^{n-1} + (\sqrt[n]{a_n})^{n-2}+\cdots +\sqrt[n]{a_n}+1|}$ what Theorem is this?

Comment: $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked.