# Proving a limit of nth-root: If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = a>0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{n}} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Let $a_n>0$ for any positive integer $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = a>0$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{n}} = 1$

My approach was to use Squeeze theorem, but I could not find the left-bound and right-bound. Thanks to Rudy the Reindeer for the solution. I overlooked the fact that the given limit is true for all $\varepsilon>0$, which allows me to take $\varepsilon$ that will give me the required bounds.

*edited, sorry for the missing $a_n$ in the given condition

*edit: Hi, I apologise if my question is not clear enough and I am still not sure what kind of questions are on-topic or off-topic since I just joined math.stackexchange recently. I tried my best to improve the question by explaining the difficulties that I face in solving this problem and I could not improve the question any further. Yet, I still do not know the specific reason on why my question is put on-hold. Thanks for the help! Have a great week ahead :)

Comment: Method 1.Take the log of $(a_n)^{1/n}$....Method 2.Prove that $x^{1/n}$ converges uniformly to $1$ for$ x \in [-k+a,a+k]$ for any $k>0.$

Comment: It is useful to know the limit of $\sqrt[n]a$. See: [Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a} =1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679304/show-that-displaystyle-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtna-1)
and [Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ by definition of limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122350/proving-lim-n-to-infty-a-frac1n-1-by-definition-of-limit).

Comment: Also this closely related question might be useful: [How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1 \rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] a_n=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084051/how-to-prove-lim-n-to-inftya-n-1-rightarrow-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-a)

Comment: You wrote: *I still do not know the specific reason on why my question is put on-hold.* From [the revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1447423/revisions) we can see that it was closed as off-topic. We do not know which specific reason was chosen, but before questions was reopened, there was a banner showing the exact reason. For example, it might have contained the text [shown here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19868). Notice that there is relatively detailed description and also a link [to this faq item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

Please state the problem correctly. The second expression is missing what you are taking the limit of, presumably $a_n$. Now for large $n, a_n$ is close to $a$, so $\sqrt[n]a_n$ is close to $\sqrt[n]a$

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $a_n \to a$ there is $N$ such that for $n \ge N$

$$ {a \over 2} \le a_n \le {3a\over 2}$$

(i.e. apply the definition of convergence with $\varepsilon ={a\over 2}$)

Next you take the $n$-th root of this inequality and then apply the squeeze theorem.