# Prove limit of $n^{th}$ root test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Given that $a_n>0, \forall{n}, \ \lim_{n \to \infty}\ a_n =a >0$, prove that$$ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sqrt[n]{a_n} =1 $$

This what I did: Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sqrt[n]{a_n} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n}} =1 $$

But I don't know whether this right. Anyone can suggest an alternative way please.

Comment: Which limit exists?

Comment: Your argument has nothing to do with the question. You attempt to prove it for only one sequence, which wouldn't be a proof even if the sequence were one of the ones being considered. However, the limit of your sequence is $0$, so it has no bearing on what is being proved in any case.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre my apologies. i forgot to specify the limit.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-fraca-n1a-n Probably also other questions linked [to 69386](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/69386) and [to 76743](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76743).

Answer (score 0):

To prove it by that way is not enough. $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is but a special case, even if you show it works on $\frac{1}{n}$, the other possible $a_n$ is still undefined.

Since $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n=a>0$,
We take $\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{2} a>0$, then there is $N_0>0$, when $n>N_0$,
$$\frac{1}{2} a<a_n<\frac{3}{2}a.$$
Thus,
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2} a}<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\sqrt[n]{\frac{3}{2}a}.$$

(You can see the choice of $\epsilon_0$ is quite arbitrary.)

By squeeze theorem you can get the result.

P. S. Proposition: For any $c>0$, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] c=1$.

Proof: For $\epsilon>0$, assume that $c>1$.
$$\begin{align}
|\sqrt[n] c-1|<\epsilon &\Leftrightarrow \sqrt[n] c < 1+\epsilon \\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n} \ln c < \ln (1+\epsilon) \\
&\Leftrightarrow n>\frac{\ln c}{\ln (1+\epsilon)}
\end{align}$$
Hence, take $N=\lceil \frac{\ln c}{\ln (1+\epsilon)} \rceil$, when $n>N$, $|\sqrt[n] c-1|<\epsilon$.

For $0<c<1$, the trick is similar. 
If $\epsilon >1$, $|\sqrt[n] c-1|<\epsilon$ always holds.

If $0<\epsilon<1$, notice that $\ln c<0$, $\ln (1-\epsilon)<0$.
$$\begin{align}
|\sqrt[n] c-1|<\epsilon &\Leftrightarrow 1-\epsilon < \sqrt[n] c \\
&\Leftrightarrow  \ln (1-\epsilon) < \frac{1}{n} \ln c\\
&\Leftrightarrow n>\frac{\ln c}{\ln (1-\epsilon)}
\end{align}$$
Hence, take $N=\lceil \frac{\ln c}{\ln (1-\epsilon)} \rceil$, when $n>N$, $|\sqrt[n] c-1|<\epsilon$.

From above we know 
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] c=1.$$

Comment: @Asydoyt i can use logarithm but i don't how to use it. Can you show me how to use it in this particular example.

Comment: @Ramos I wrote a proof. See if you can understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a>1$. Let $b_n=\sqrt[n]{a_n}-1$. If we prove $b_n \rightarrow 0$, we are done.

We know that:

$$1+nb_n \leq (1+b_n)^n=a_n.$$

This implies:

$$b_n \leq \frac{ a_n-1}{n}.$$

Since we are supposing $a>1$, we also have that (at least for sufficiently large $n$):

$$0 \leq b_n.$$

Combining both inequalities and using the squeeze theorem yields the result.

In the case that $a<1$, apply the previous result with the sequence $\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{a_n}}$.

Comment: If $a < 1$, let $a = 1/(1+b)$. Then $(1+b)^n > 1+nb > nb$ so $a^n < 1/(nb)$. All this is in "What is Mathematics" by Courant and Robbins. Similarly, $(1+n^{-1/2})^n > 1+n^{1/2} > n^{1/2}$ so $n^{1/n} < (1+n^{-1/2})^2 < 1+3n^{-1/2} \to 1$.