# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\binom{2n}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>
> without using Limit as a sum and stirling Approximation.

$\bf{My\; Try:}$ Using $$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{n}{r}^2$$

Using $\bf{Cauchy\; Schwarz}$ Inequality

$$\left[\sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{n}{r}^2\right]\cdot \left[\sum^{n}_{r=0}1\right]\geq \left(\sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{n}{r}\right)^2 = 2^{2n} = 4^n$$

So $$\frac{4^n}{n+1}<\sum^{n}_{r=0}\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$$

But i did not understand how can i calculate upper bound such that i can apply the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: Note that $\binom{2n}{n}$ must be larger than the average of all the $\binom{2n}{k}$, which is $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$. This isn't quite as good as your bound, but it's definitely good enough, and I think it's a lot more straightforward than your Cauchy-Schwarz argument...

Comment: Evaluate a $\underline{limit}$ $\texttt{without}$ using $\underline{limit}$ ?.

Comment: There are literally a handful of duplicates of this question all over the site.  Asking not to use "limit as a sum" doesn't make sense given that you are using Cauchy-Schwarz.  Be more precise about what you are not allowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upper bound is way more trivial than the lower bound through the CS inequality:
$$ \binom{2n}{n}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} = 2^{2n} = 4^n.$$

Answer (score 9):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76800/23249)).

We have that
$$
\frac{{2n+2\choose n+1}}{{2n\choose n}}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\to4
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Hence, the limit is $4$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> By "$\textsf{using limits}$", the *Stoltz-Ces$\grave{a}$ro Theorem* yields:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n}\,\ln\pars{{2n \choose n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\ln\pars{{2\bracks{n + 1} \choose n + 1}} -
\ln\pars{{2n \choose n }} \over \pars{n + 1} - n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\pars{{2n + 2 \choose n+1} \over {2n \choose n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\pars{\bracks{2n + 2}\bracks{2n + 1} \over
\bracks{n + 1}\bracks{n + 1}} = \ln\pars{4}
\end{align}

---

$$
 \color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{2n \choose n}^{1/n}} = \color{#f00}{4}
$$