# How to see that $\lim \frac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}=e$?

Tags: calculus, limits

There is a way to see that $\lim \frac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}=e$ from these definitions?

$$e=\lim\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{\frac1k};\quad e=\sum\frac1{k!}$$

If it is not possible, how to deal with the limit of the title to get it limit? Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

(it does not follow directly from your definitions though)

You can use Stirling formula:

$$k!\underset{k\to\infty}{\sim} \sqrt{2\pi k}\frac{k^k}{e^k}.$$

Comment: I dont know the topic of Stirling approximation very well, I assume that $\sim$ means equivalence in the infinity, right?

Comment: @Masacroso Yes that right. (it means approximately that the quotient tends to $1$)

Comment: @Masacroso It means that the ratio of the both sides tends to $1$ (not approximately, but exactly).

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb It is only true if one of the sides is never equal to $0$. That's why I said *approximately*.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76800/23249)).

We have that
$$
\frac n{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\biggl(\frac{n^n}{n!}\biggr)^{1/n}
$$
and let us denote $a_n=n^n/n!$. Then
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\biggl(1+\frac1n\biggr)^n\to e\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Hence,
$$
a_n^{1/n}=\frac n{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\to e\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is the origin of my question, the equivalence in the calculus of the radius of convergence of a power series when $a_k=\frac{k!}{k^k}$. This is why I want to know if we can evaluate the limit from a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$ \ln\frac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}=\ln k-\frac1k\ln(k!)=-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{k}\ln\frac{i}{k}\to-\int_0^1\ln xdx=1$$
as $k\to\infty$, one has
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}=e. $$