# if $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\to \rho$, then $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\to \rho$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\rho.$$

How can I show that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\rho$ ?

---

**Atempts** $$|\sqrt[n]{a_n}-\rho|=\frac{|a_n-\rho|}{a_n^{n-1}+\rho a_n^{n-2}+...+\rho^{n-1}},$$
but I'm not so sure why the RHS goes to 0 when $n\to \infty $.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69386/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76800/42969

Comment: $\ln(a_{n+1})-\ln(a_n)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ln\rho$ thus using Cesaro's theorem, $\frac{\ln a_n}{n}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ln\rho$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\rho$.

Comment: What do you mean by Cesaro ? The only Cesaro theorem I know is $x_n\to \ell$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\to \ell$. You use this one ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Take the $\ln$ and apply Cesaro.

Comment: What do you mean by Cesaro ? The only Cesaro theorem I know is $x_n\to \ell$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\to \ell$. You use this one ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this one !

Answer (score -1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. There is $N$ s.t. $$(\rho-\varepsilon)|a_{n-1}| \leq |a_{n}|\leq (1+\varepsilon )|a_{n-1}|, $$
for all $n>N$. And thus, if $n>N$, $$(\rho-\varepsilon )^{n-N}|a_{N}|\leq |a_n|\leq (\rho+\varepsilon )^{n-N}|a_N|,$$
i.e. $$(\rho-\varepsilon )^{\frac{n-N}{n}}\leq \sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq (\rho+\varepsilon )^{\frac{n-N}{n}}.$$

Therefore $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \rho +\varepsilon \quad \text{and}\quad \liminf_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}\geq \rho-\varepsilon .$$

Since the result hold for all $\varepsilon >0$, the claim follow.

Comment: Why do you use limsup and liminf and not the limit directly ?

Comment: Because, there is no reason that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ exist a priori.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point, you prove that $\rho-\varepsilon \leq \lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \rho+\varepsilon $, and thus, since this hold for all $\varepsilon $, the limit exist, no ?

Comment: Well, you can't do that's way. $a_n\leq b_n\leq c_n$ for all $n$ and $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$, doesn't implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty }b_n$ exist (here $a$ and $b$ are different, so squeeze theorem doesn't apply if you were thinking about that). A simple example $-1\leq (-1)^n\leq 1$....