# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}$ using Stirling's approximation

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Although it is a very simple question, I am not able to get similar results using Stirling's approximation as obtained using Integration. Here is what I have attempted.

> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^{n}}\right)^{1/n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e}n^{1/2n}\end{aligned}$$

I am not able to reason out as to how this will evaluate to $1/e$. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Could you cite some resource so that I can read about this proposition and where it comes from.

Comment: [How to show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1) has some answers that might be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_n \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_n \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ if the last limits exists. So $$\lim_n (\sqrt{2\pi n})^{1/n}=\lim_n \frac{\sqrt{2\pi (n+1)}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}=\sqrt{\lim_n \frac{n+1}{n}}=1$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you tell what this result is called?

Comment: I don0t know... is a classical result on limits of sequences. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-a-n1-n-is-equal-to-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-a-n) you can found a proof

Comment: This is essentially [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) applied to the logarithm.