# Inequality concerning limsup and liminf of Cesaro mean of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $y_n = \frac{(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)}{n}$.

**(a)** Prove that $\liminf x_n \le \liminf y_n \le \limsup y_n \le \limsup x_n$

**(b)** Give an example of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ for which all inequalities of part (a) are strict.

I honestly have no idea where to start on this. I can observe some of the easier things such as $\lim \inf x_n  \le \lim \sup x_n$ Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the result from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means) is a consequence of the result from your question.  On the other hand, the result mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73508/an-exercise-on-liminf-and-limsup/73709#73709) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/limit-of-quotient-of-two-series/100542#100542) can be considered as a generalization.

Comment: And now I found also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193157/if-sigma-n-fracs-1s-2-cdotss-nn-then-operatornamelim-sup-sigma) which seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note $\limsup y_m \leq \sup_{ m\geq n} x_m $

This must be true right? Because either the right hand side is $\infty$, in which case, it is trivial, or it is not. Suppose not, let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = M$, and $\sup_{ m\geq n} x_m= x$

$y_m = \dfrac{M + x_{n+1}+... + x_m}{m} \leq \dfrac{M+(m-n)x}{m}$ for $m\geq n$

So we have $\limsup y_m \leq \lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{M+(m-n)x}{m} = x = \sup_{ m\geq n} x_m$

We now take the limit in $n$ obtain the right handside. If you use the fact $\limsup -y_m = - \liminf y_m$, you get the other inequality. The middle one is trivial. For examples, see the hint above.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how $\dfrac{M+(m-n)x}{m} = x$? Doesn't that mean that $M = nx$?

Comment: @Archie I forgot add lim... Notice that term clearly has a lim, so lim = limsup

Comment: Ah! Makes sense now. I realized my previous work was wrong after finding a counter-example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Archie should have said so.

Comment: Sorry about that! :(

Comment: @Archie no worries.

Comment: I accepted it. :D

Comment: @Archie I was only kidding :P, but thanks :) I did learn quite a bit from this question though. it is good to do it once.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :  a] just to give you the idea :

Think of a seq. $x_n$ whose limsup is  $100$ -- how can you expect that limsup of averages

is $101$ while there are infinitely many terms in the tail of $x_n$ less than $101$?

b]try  $x_n=(-1)^n (2n-1)=-1, 3,-5 ,7, -9, 11,-13,15,-17,19 $ , . .

Comment: And for (b)
$\lim \sup x_n = \infty
\\ \lim \inf x_n = -\infty
\\ \lim \sup y_n = 1
\\ \lim \inf y_n = -1?$

Comment: @HalilDuru hold on a second there, I don't think it is not that simple. sup is for $\sup_{m\geq n}$ and $y_n$ is the average of the first $n$ terms? how is the max of the terms after n comparable to the average of first $n$ terms.

Comment: @Using what you said, you can prove $y_n \leq \max_{m\leq n} x_n$, well if you take limsup on both side, the right hand side is not $\limsup x_n$, just consider the sequence $1/n$

Comment: @Archie you might want to post your proof, if it is correct, it will enlighten me, but I don't think this is the correct approach.

Comment: This wasn't what i meant lost1--Think of a seq. $x_n$ whose limsup is  $100$ - how can you expect that limsup of averages is 101 while there are infinitely many terms in the tail of $x_n$ less than 101?

Comment: This version is clearer and not misleading i suppose as a hint..

Comment: yes, because it is not as simple as you put it max >= average...